# How to change my avatar in WTelegramClient

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

Currently I am using [WTelegramClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WTelegramClient/) library on C#, how can I change my telegram account avatar, I can't find instructions in [EXAMPLES](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md)

Answer (score 1):

If your picture resides currently on your computer, uploading it as your new account profile picture is as easy as:

```cs
var inputFile = await client.UploadFileAsync(@"C:\Pictures\Me.jpg");
await client.Photos_UploadProfilePhoto(inputFile);
```